# XAML grid not auto scaling

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to write a Universal app with a grid with 2 columns and 6 rows, each box containing a textblock. I want the grid to auto scale with the window size, and later on I will get the text scaling with the window as well.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1070" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1900">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="DaoTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="736" FontSize="100" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="EthTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="736" FontSize="100" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="LtcTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="736" FontSize="100" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="DgeTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="736" FontSize="100" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="LumTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="736" FontSize="100" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="RipTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="736" FontSize="100" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"/>
    </Grid>
```

This doesn't auto scale with the window - the text goes off the screen, and when I resize the window, the text just stays in place and goes off the screen. How can I make the grid resize with the size of the window?

Comment: Do not use HorizontalAligment,Height, VerticalAligment, neither Width, with that you are forcing the size don't you see it? Apart you should use Auto in the Height of each RowDefinition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid should look like this if you want to get it to stretch to the window boundaries

```
<Grid Margin="10,10,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock x:Name="DaoTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="736" FontSize="100" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="EthTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="736" FontSize="100" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="LtcTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="736" FontSize="100" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="DgeTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="736" FontSize="100" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="LumTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="736" FontSize="100" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="RipTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="736" FontSize="100" TextAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="textBlock_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: So essentially you want to get rid of `Width/Height/VerticalAlignment` from the original version.

I'd also wanted to add that for row height/column width - * is the default, so no need for all of those `Height="*"` qualifiers.